# Terraform | How to aws access/secret key from provider for a module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codebuild

**Question:** I am trying to reference the environments `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` inside a terraform module which uses AWS CodeBuild projects. The credentials are being loaded from a shared credentials file.

In my terraform project

**main.tf**

```bash
# master profile
provider "aws" {
  alias       = "master"
  max_retries = "5"
  profile     = "master"
  region      = var.region
}

# env profile
provider "aws" {
  max_retries = "5"
  region      = var.region
  profile     = "dev-terraform"
}
module "code_build" {
  source = "../../modules/code_build"
  ...
}
```

**code_build.tf**

```bash
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "sls_deploy" {
  ...
  environment {
    ...
    environment_variable {
      name  = "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
      value = "(Trying to read the aws access key from the aws provider profile env)
    }
```

Can anyone explain how I can reference the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from the provider credentials specified in main.tf?

Comment: If the credentials are loaded from a shared file, then they are not environment variables, and therefore cannot be accessed elsewhere in the config. You can refactor to transmit the credentials as variables input from environment variables, and then they would be accessible.

Comment: in addition to what @MattSchuchard said, your main.tf is referencing your local AWS Profile Config... `~/.aws/credentials` & I'm wondering if your AWS CodeBuild Project could reference those credentials in AWS SSM Parameter Store.

Comment: You should use a service role instead of static credentials https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/setting-up.html#setting-up-service-role

Comment: @paulg The credentials are being loaded from ~/.aws/credentials and terraform is picking those up. I'm not sure how to grab those credential values and reference them in my CodeBuild projects. I thought about SSM but thought that may not be very secure storing creds in parameter store.

Comment: @MattSchuchard is there a way to grab the access keys from ~/.aws/credentials when running terraform?

Comment: You don't need to store anything in SSM. You can use the serice role to do what it is supposed to do. Is there any kind of cross account access involved? If so, you still don't need AWS keys, rather an IAM role.

Comment: @MarkoE For CodeBuild, there is nothing that requires cross account access. I just have to pass in the two access keys as environment variables so serverless can use them with authentication. WIth a service role, how can it pass the access key and secret access keys to the environment to CodeBuild?

Comment: You don't need access keys because by using the role it will have permisson to peform actions on different services.